# Why does Bootstrap 3.1.1 reverse column order?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, grid

In Bootstrap 3.1.1 the column orders seem to be reversed. Why is this? How may it be safely overridden?

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 4</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

My fist thought is to just add:

```
[class^="col"] {
  float: left;
}
```

However it seems odd that Bootstrap would ship with this behavior if there weren't using it to achieve something intentionally that I'm just missing. That said, if it should be removed, could adding the float I posted above unintentionally break anything else or that the best solution?

NB: For what it's worth Bootstrap 3.3.7 (latest) seems to have reversed the floating rule:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are referencing the `bootstrap-rtl` version. RTL stands for "Right To Left". If you fix it and use the standard version, it works fine:

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">col 4</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```